# How Header should be formed in soap Message

Tags: xml, soap

In soap message IN header tag whether immediate child must be complex element or may be complex element?

eg:

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <Tran1>1</Tran1>
  <Tran2>2</Tran2>
  <Tran5>5</Tran5>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Comment: Yes, this is a normal thing. What is your question?

Comment: whether the above eg is possible ? @Marcel